# Several group by in pyspark by different columns

Tags: pyspark, bigdata, azure-databricks

i have a big table in databricks, this table have 500 columns and i want to calculate a groupBy by each column like that.

list_grp = [df_ref_crt.groupBy('SEGMENT',colum).count().withColumnRenamed(colum,"new_name").withColumn('variable',lit(colum)) for colum in df_ref_crt.columns]

The code works but is too slow, so my question is if there another way to do faster.
(the purpose of this is calculate PSI and this is the reference, of course there is another group by that a have to do respecto same variables and Period.)
thanks....

Comment: You should add more info: what is PSI, how to calculate it, how the other `groupBy` looks. I don't see what could be improved based on the data you provided. However, it can probably be done if you told in detail what will you do with these dataframes later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the Databricks perform by implementing below suggestions. This will definitely improve your execution performance:

**Use larger cluster:** General cluster configuration with two workers with four cores each takes forever to do anything. **It’s actually not any more expensive to use a large cluster for a workload than it is to use a smaller one. It’s just faster.**

Note that you’re renting the cluster for the length of the workload. So, if you spin up that two worker cluster and it takes an hour, you’re paying for those workers for the full hour. However, if you spin up a four worker cluster and it takes only half an hour, the cost is actually the same!

[image]

**Delta Cache:** If you’re using regular clusters, be sure to use the L series or E series on Azure Databricks. This will have fast SSDs and caching enabled by default.

[image]

You can refer the Microsoft official document to know more about [optimization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/optimizations/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did it and in fact the cluster could with an even bigger table! In my case, Delta Cache is the only option that i take. Cluster cannot be configured...